# How to get most accurate location?

Tags: geolocation, gis, latitude-longitude

I have unclean records of shops. Each shop's location has been entered multiple times with different lat/lon. Is there anyway to get the most accurate one?

Answer (score 0):

There is no automated way to get the most accurate coordinates unless you have a data set to test against. You could calculate the [mean location](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/mean-center.htm) of the points for each shop however this is going to be affected by inaccurate coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how your data looks.
If the data is just noisy, average the coordinates.

Otherwise, what you could do is try to use a service like Google Maps to find coordinates instead of asking users to enter them.

If you have much data, you'll probably want to automate it. If it's 10 locations or so, just get your hands dirty and manually fix it. :)

If you give some more detailed information, I could give a more detailed answer.